# Blazor InputSelect doesn't work in some cases

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor

I want to use a dropdown list (select) to pass some values later on.
So,I am calling .razor components where I have InputSelect.

```html
<EditForm Model="para">

    <Test Text="Para" Value="@para.Selected" Units="@units"></Test> <span>Selected string:  @para.Selected</span>

</EditForm>

<EditForm Model="selectParameters">   
        <TestAsParameter Para="selectParameters"></TestAsParameter> <span>Selected string:  @selectParameters.Value</span>    
</EditForm>
<br />
<button class="btn btn-primary my-2" @onclick="Calculate">Calculate</button>

@code
{
    List<string> units = new List<string>() { "m", "cm", "mm" };
    Parameters para;
    SelectParameters selectParameters { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        // set initial values
        para = new Parameters();
        para.List = units;
        para.Selected = para.List[0];

        selectParameters = new SelectParameters();
        selectParameters.Text = "Select parameters";
        selectParameters.Value = "mm";
        selectParameters.Units = units;
    }

    private void Calculate()
    {

    }

    public class Parameters
    {
        public List<string> List { get; set; }
        public string Selected { get; set; }
    }
```

When I call this "Test.razor" component it does not bind "para.selected" to selected value, this value is only set at initialization time latter not.

```html
<div class="my-2">

    @if (Text.Length > 0)
    {
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-lg-3">@Text</label>
    }
    <InputSelect @bind-Value="@Value" class="col-2">
        @foreach (var unit in Units)
        {
            <option value="@unit.ToString()">@unit</option>
        }
    </InputSelect>

</div>  

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string Values { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public List<string> Units { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}
```

If I set new object with prameters than the bidning is OK and returned value is as is selected.
Call to "TestAsParameter.razor"

```html
<div class="my-2">
    @if (Para.Text.Length > 0)
    {
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-lg-3">@Para.Text</label>
    }
    <InputSelect @bind-Value="@Para.Value" class="col-2">
        @foreach (var unit in Para.Units)
        {
            <option value="@unit">@unit</option>
        }
    </InputSelect>
</div>


@code {

    [Parameter]
    public SelectParameters Para { get; set; }

}
```

Here is new object

```html
   public class SelectParameters
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string Value {  get; set;}
        public List<string> Units { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    }
```

Can someone explain why InputSelect doesn't work in Test.razor but works in TestAsParameter.razor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<EditForm Model="para">

   <Test Text="Para" Value="@para.Selected" Units="@units"></Test> 
      <span>Selected string:  @para.Selected</span>
```

`Test` is a child component nested in an EditForm component. In order for `Test` to be part of the EditForm's logics, you must pass the Model as a parameter to the Test Component. You can do something like this:

```
<Test Model="para"></Test>
```

I've removed the following setting: `Value="@para.Selected" Units="@units"`
as they are superfluous because the model instance `para` contains these values.
Incidentally, the attribute parameter named Value has its counterpart defined in the Test component as `Values` . No error ??? I know why not, but I won't start confusing you right now. The following is how your Test component should look like:

### Test.razor

```
<div class="my-2">

    <InputSelect @bind-Value="Model.Selected" class="col-2">
        @foreach (var unit in Model.List)
        {
           @if (unit != null && String.Equals(unit, Model.Selected, 
                                   StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
           {
               <option selected value="@unit">@unit</option>
           }
           else
           {
               <option value="@unit.ToString()">@unit</option>
           }
        }
    </InputSelect>
 </div>  

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public Parameters Model{ get; set; }
}
```

And this is how you embed your Test component in the EditForm component:

```
    <EditForm Model="para">
       <Test Model="para"></Test><span>Selected string:  @para.Selected</span>
    </EditForm>
```

That is all for the Test component. If you need some enlightment about TestAsParameter.razor, tell me.

Note: I have typed the answer here without testing it...

Comment: what you are suggesting is what I have done with SelectParameters at TestAsParameter.razor and is working. But why doesn't work when you have multiple parameters in child component like I have  
'[Parameter]
    public string Text { get; set; }
[Parameter]
public string Value { get; set; }
[Parameter]
public List<string> Units { get; set; } = new List<string>();'
And when a change to Value (para.Selected) is made there is no change in '<span>Selected string:  @para.Selected</span>' but when passed as only one Parameter then works. Why so @enet?

Comment: That's exactly what I've written in my answer: "Test is a child component nested in an EditForm component. In order for Test to be part of the EditForm's logics, you must pass the Model as a parameter to the Test Component. " Once again, you must pass the Model object to the Test component. The Model object is used by both, the EditForm component and the Test component. You can't make the Test component independent of the parent component (EditForm). That is why when you create a cart form that spans over a couple of pages, data validation always affects the whole cart widget.

Comment: You can't create stand alone pages for each part of the Model. Of course, ordinarily, you can create a parent component and a child component that is passed parameter values from the parent, and act upon these values as you did in your Test Component. But the EditComponent was designed to use a Model, and each of its constituent components that use binding to Input Forms  components, must be bound to the Model... Would you mind marking it as the answer if it solved your problem, so others know it was useful.